# Aligning a node at center of another node

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, tikz-node

I want to align a black circle at the center of another bigger white circle (it must be look like to `Activity Final Node` of `UML`).

The most straightforward is to simply explicitly place the bigger circle nodes at certain coordinates and calculate the coordinates of black one by hand; but it is not possible to use that way for difficult graphics without wasting time.

I could do some thing like this:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (close){Close};
  %defining "end process" node:
  \node [circle, below =of close, text width=2em, fill=none, draw=black] (stop-outer){};
  \node [circle, below =1.2 of close, text width=1em, fill=black] (stop-inner){};
  %end of defining "end process" node
  \draw [->] (close) -- (stop-outer);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

But also it has its disadvantages, for example I have to care in about `text width` of bigger circle and change the numerical part of `below =1.2 of close` to get best result.

Is there a way to do that without need to calculating by hands?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have more possibilities:

- define common anchor for circles and use different circle radius (if correct understand, you not liked this solution)
- first draw inner circle and around it fit outer:

```
 \documentclass[tikz,margin=3mm]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{fit, positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (close){Close};
  %defining "end process" node:
  \node [circle, draw, 
         fill=black, text width=1em, 
         below = of close] (stop) {};
  \node [circle, draw, inner sep =0.2em,
         fit = (stop) ] (stop-outer) {};
  %end of defining "end process" node
  \draw [->] (close) -- (stop-outer);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

- use option `double` for draw one circle:

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{fit, positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (close){Close};
  \node [circle, draw, double, double distance=0.2em,
         fill=black, text width=1em, outer sep=0.1em,
         below = of close] (stop) {};
 \draw [->] (close) -- (stop);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

in both later cases the result is the same:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Using `positionning` center and `anchor` :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (close){Close};
  % defining "end process" node:
  \node [circle, below =of close, text width=2em, fill=none, draw=black] (stop-outer){};
  \node [circle, below=0mm of stop-outer.center, anchor=center, text width=1em, fill=black] (stop-inner){};
  % end of defining "end process" node
  \draw [->] (close) -- (stop-outer);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Or just: `\node [circle, text width=1em, fill=black] at (stop-outer) (stop-inner) {};`